# Jython and standalone DB connection pool: How to confirm the pool is a Singleton

Tags: java, tomcat, database-connection, jython, connection-pooling

**Question:** Can you use the `zxJDBC.connectx` method, outside of an application server container?

I have my own server application in Jython, and I'm looking to upgrade to using a database connection pool (since I'm building and destroying individual connections manually, at this point). I have found some sample code and have gotten it to work (using Tomcat's connection pool), but something about the way it works bothers me. To me, it looks like the pool is getting created over and over again. Here's my working example:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC

params = { }
params['url'] = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database'
params['driverClassName'] = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
params['username'] = 'mario'
params['password'] = 'myP@ssw0rd'
params['validationQuery'] = 'SELECT 1'
params['jdbcInterceptors'] = \
    'org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;' + \
    'org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer'

# This is the line that worries me!
conn = zxJDBC.connectx('org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource', **params)

with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM MyTable')
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    print data

conn.close()
```

Take a look at "the line that worries me." I would like to use the `zxJDBC` connection object, but if each time I obtain it I have to give the DataSource class name along with the setup parameters, then the first thing I think is that a connection pool is being created anew each time. That's *obviously* not what I want.

Does anyone know for sure what's going on, or how I might go about confirming what's going on—with a little experimentation, perhaps? Am I supposed to duplicate the JNDI infrastructure of a servlet container or something if I want to use this in my server? Am I failing to understand what exactly a `DataSource` is and how it works? I don't know how to get to the bottom of it. Thanks!

---

**Edit: Jython source code**

I took a look at the Jython source code. The `connectx` method is backed by the `com.ziclix.python.sql.connect.Connectx` class. The relevant snippet looks like this:

```
/**
 * Construct a javax.sql.DataSource or javax.sql.ConnectionPooledDataSource
 */
@Override
public PyObject __call__(PyObject[] args, String[] keywords) {
    Connection c = null;
    PyConnection pc = null;
    Object datasource = null;
    PyArgParser parser = new PyArgParser(args, keywords);

    try {
        String klass = (String) parser.arg(0).__tojava__(String.class);
        datasource = Class.forName(klass).newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw zxJDBC.makeException(zxJDBC.DatabaseError, "unable to instantiate datasource");
    }

    /* 
     * The code continues on, setting up the connection pool's parameters, 
     * handling errors, etc., and obtaining a connection (variable: c). 
     */

    try {
        if (c == null || c.isClosed()) {
            throw zxJDBC.makeException(zxJDBC.DatabaseError, "unable to establish connection");
        }

        pc = new PyConnection(c);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw zxJDBC.makeException(zxJDBC.DatabaseError, e);
    }

    return pc;
}
```

Building Jython from source isn't all that easy (there appear to be not well-documented dependencies), or I would put in some debugging statements to compare the `datasource` objects. But when I try to duplicate the creation part on my own...

```
datasource = Class.forName(klass).newInstance();
```

...it looks to me like unique `DataSource` instances (and therefore, presumably, unique pool instances) are being created with each call.

Does anyone have any experience with Jython and know for sure? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research, I have come up with the following solution.

Instead of using the more direct approach shown in most Jython example code, I instantiate a `DataSource` using Java methods. (I took this from example code on the Apache Tomcat site.) Then, instead of calling a zxJDBC method to obtain a connection object, I make use of what that method relies on: namely, the `com.ziclix.python.sql.PyConnection` class.

The result is a traditional Java connection object drawn from a pool, which is then wrapped in a PyConnection object, allowing for the convenience of a Jython connection and its cursor object.

```
from __future__ import with_statement

from com.ziclix.python.sql import PyConnection
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool as pool

# https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html
p = pool.PoolProperties()
p.setUrl('jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database')
p.setDriverClassName('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
p.setUsername('mario')
p.setPassword('myP@ssw0rd')
p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1")
p.setJdbcInterceptors('org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;' + 
                      'org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer')

datasource = pool.DataSource()
datasource.setPoolProperties(p)

# http://www.jython.org/javadoc/com/ziclix/python/sql/PyConnection.html
conn = PyConnection(datasource.getConnection())

with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM MyTable')
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    print data

conn.close()
```

I have more confidence in this approach. Is there any reason why I shouldn't?